# What are my rights if I miss a flight due to a schedule change

Tags: air-travel, cancellations, passenger-rights

I was booked on a flight from Dublin to London and the airline emailed me to say that the flight was cancelled and I have been booked on a flight the day before.  If I had not seen this email (I didn't see it for several weeks) and had turned up at the airport on the original date, what would be my rights?  The original flight was cancelled and no flights from the carrier were going that day.

Comment: Did you check the airline's terms, contract of carriage, etc?  I'll bet there's a clause that says "I agree to receive flight updates by email and that this will constitute adequate notification."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(IANAL, take with a grain of salt).

They sent an email **weeks in advance**, to warn you, they even offered a new booking.

You did not see it.

You'd need to prove that you really did not see it; that's pretty much impossible.

IMO, You don't have many recourses; a clear case of user error.

Sorry.